# MySQL insert, increment column value per same id

Tags: mysql

I have this table `relations`

```
ID    Name    Parent   Pos
================================
1     Alex       1      1
2     Mary       1      2
3     John       1      3
4     Doe        2      1
5     Bob        2      2
6     Kate       2      3
```

Before i do an `insert` query, i select the `Parent` id and get the last `Pos` position and then increment by 1.

```
$data = $DB2->query("SELECT * FROM relations 
            WHERE Parent='1' ORDER BY `Pos` DESC LIMIT 1");

            $results = $data->result_array();

            foreach($results as $row) {
                $pos = $row['Pos'];  //last position

            }


$pos = $pos + 1;
    $DB2->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO relations (Name,Parent,Pos) VALUES('test',1,'$pos')");
```

Is there a way i can auto-increment the `Pos` column per `Parent` column?  Or is my current way most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about race conditions (two inserts happening at the same time), then you can do this in a single statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO relations (Name, Parent, Pos) 
    SELECT 'test', 1, MAX(pos) + 1
    FROM relations
    WHERE Parent = 1;
```

However, I would definitely advise you to have a unique index on `(Parent, Pos)`, and to remove the `IGNORE` -- if an error occurs, you want to know about it.

You can make this safer by using a trigger for the assignment.  You could also lock the table so no other inserts can happen during a particular insert.  This is an expensive operation and can slow down the system if there is a heavy transaction load.

Comment: yes i am worried about race conditions.  Is your method the best approach to avoid race conditions?

Comment: @mdnba50 . . . A unique index on `(Parent, Pos)` is probably sufficient, so long as the application code can recover from a failed insert.  Otherwise, you'll have to go into locking.